# How to Add a Logo to Each Page of HTML Content and Generate a PDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm facing an issue generating a PDF by adding a logo to HTML content so that it appears on every page. Here's my code snippet:

```
generatePDF = () => {
    // Logo görüntüsünü içeren bir img etiketi oluşturun
    const logoImg = document.createElement("img");
    logoImg.src = logo; // Logo görüntüsünün yolu
    logoImg.style.position = "relative"; // Position it absolutely within the container
    logoImg.style.left = "20px"; // Sol kenardan 20px içeriye yerleştirin
    logoImg.style.top = "20px"; // Üst kenardan 20px içeriye yerleştirin
    logoImg.style.maxHeight = "50mm"; // Maksimum yükseklik
    logoImg.style.maxWidth = "50mm"; // Maksimum genişlik

    // Container div oluşturun ve her sayfa için logo ve HTML içeriğini içine ekleyin
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.style.position = "relative";
    container.appendChild(logoImg); // Logo her sayfada eklenir

    // HTML2PDF kütüphanesini kullanarak PDF oluşturun
    const opt = {
      filename: "logo_and_html.pdf",
      image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 1 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: { unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait" },
    };

    // İlk sayfa için içerik div'ini oluşturun
    let currentPageContent = this.createNewPageContentDiv(container);

    // HTML içeriğini alın
    const htmlContent = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

    // HTML içeriğini içeren bir div oluşturun
    currentPageContent.innerHTML = htmlContent;

    // HTML2PDF kütüphanesini kullanarak PDF oluşturun
    html2pdf()
      .from(container)
      .set(opt)
      .set({
        pagebreak: { mode: "avoid-all", before: "#page2el" },
      })
      .save();
  };

  createNewPageContentDiv(container) {
    // Yeni bir sayfa için içerik div'i oluşturun
    const newPageContent = document.createElement("div");
    newPageContent.style.marginLeft = "50px"; // HTML içeriğini soldan 50px içeriye yerleştirir
    newPageContent.style.marginTop = "30px"; // HTML içeriğini üstten 30px içeriye yerleştirir
    newPageContent.style.marginRight = "50px";
    // Container'a içerik div'ini ekleyin
    container.appendChild(newPageContent);

    return newPageContent;
  }
```

Despite using this method to add the logo to each page, I'm still unsuccessful. How can I display the logo on every page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the logo is displayed on every page of the PDF generated using HTML2PDF, you need to use the `afterPageContent` option provided by HTML2PDF. This option allows you to add content after each page is generated.

```
 generatePDF = () => {
    // HTML2PDF options
    const opt = {
        filename: "logo_and_html.pdf",
        image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 1 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
        jsPDF: { unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait" },
        pagebreak: { mode: "avoid-all", before: "#page2el" },
        afterPageContent: (currentPage, pageCount) => {
            const logoImg = document.createElement("img");
            logoImg.src = logo; 
            logoImg.style.position = "absolute"; 
            logoImg.style.left = "20px"; 
            logoImg.style.top = "20px"; 
            logoImg.style.maxHeight = "50mm"; 
            logoImg.style.maxWidth = "50mm"; 
            const logoContainer = document.createElement("div");
            logoContainer.style.position = "relative";
            logoContainer.appendChild(logoImg);

            return logoContainer;
        }
    };

    html2pdf()
        .from(document.body)
        .set(opt)
        .save();
};
```

Comment: with this method the logo does not appear on any page